# (Python Code) Can't call my new field in new object which extend from mrp.bom in OpenERP v7?

Tags: python, function, odoo

Below is my coding which I have create:

```
class mrp_extend(osv.Model):

    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        result = {}

        for bom_line_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            result[bom_line_obj.id] = bom_line_obj.product_id.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00
        return result 

    def _get_product_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        result = {}

        for bom_line_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            result[bom_line_obj.id] = (bom_line_obj.product_id.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00) * (bom_line_obj.product_qty or 0.00)
        return result 

    def get_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            total_cost = 0.0
            for line_rec in rec.bom_lines:
                total_cost += line_rec.product_total_cost or 0.0
            res.update({rec.id : total_cost})
        return res

    _columns = {
        'product_unit_cost' : fields.function(_get_unit_cost, string="Product Unit Cost", digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'product_total_cost' : fields.function(_get_product_total_cost, string="Total Product Unit Cost", digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'total_cost' : fields.function(get_total_cost, string="Total Cost", digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'mrp_bom_ids' : fields.one2many('mrp.extend.bom', 'mrp_extend_id', 'MRP Extend', states={'done': [('readonly', False)]})
    }

    _defaults = {
        'total_cost': lambda *a: 0.0,
    }

    def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, name, context=None):
        """ Changes UoM and name if product_id changes.
        @param name: Name of the field
        @param product_id: Changed product_id
        @return:  Dictionary of changed values
        """
        if product_id:
            prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
            return {'value': {'name': prod.name, 'product_uom': prod.uom_id.id, 'product_unit_cost': prod.standard_price}}
        return {}

    def onchange_uom(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, product_uom, context=None):
        res = {'value':{}}
        if not product_uom or not product_id:
            return res
        product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
        uom = self.pool.get('product.uom').browse(cr, uid, product_uom, context=context)
        if uom.category_id.id != product.uom_id.category_id.id:
            res['warning'] = {'title': _('Warning'), 'message': _('The Product Unit of Measure you chose has a different category than in the product form.')}
            res['value'].update({'product_uom': product.uom_id.id})
        return res


class mrp_production_extend(osv.Model):

    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    def _get_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        bom_point = self.pool.get('mrp.bom').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        total_cost = bom_point.total_cost or 0.00
        product_qty = bom_point.product_qty or 0.00
        if product_qty > 1:
            total_cost = total_cost / product_qty
        return total_cost 

    _columns = {
        #Add by Henry on 07Nov2013
        #'total_cost' : fields.float('Total Cost', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'total_cost' : fields.function(_get_total_cost, string="Total Cost", digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'pre_set_qty' : fields.float('Pre Set Quantity', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure')),
        'total_final_cost' : fields.float('Total Final Cost', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
        'mrp_production_ids' : fields.one2many('mrp.production.extend.bom', 'mrp_production_extend_id', 'MRP Production Extend', states={'done': [('readonly', False)]})
        #-----------------------------
    }
```

I have new create 2 object. One is mrp_extend and this object is inherit from mrp.bom.

Then I have create new object name mrp_production_extend and this object is inherit from mrp.production.

Now my problem is, I have create a function in mrp_production_extend:

```
def _get_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        bom_point = self.pool.get('mrp.bom').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        total_cost = bom_point.total_cost or 0.00
        product_qty = bom_point.product_qty or 0.00
        if product_qty > 1:
            total_cost = total_cost / product_qty
        return total_cost
```

but this function no work and show me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'browse_record_list' object has no attribute 'total_cost'
```

WHY? because in my mrp_extend object I have inherit to mrp.bom and create new total_cost. Anything I do wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of a functional field should be a dictionary of the form `{<record_id>: <record functional field value>}`. You can get the details of functional fields from [Here](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html/#functional-fields). In your function `def _get_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):', the argument ids contain list of ids of the records for which the functional field is being calculated. So if you try to browse using the ids as`bom_point = self.pool.get('mrp.bom').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)', you will get a list of browse records. So you have to loop through this browse record list and return your result. ie;

```
def _get_total_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = {}        
    for bom_point in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        total_cost = bom_point.bom_id.total_cost or 0.00
        product_qty = bom_point.bom_id.product_qty or 0.00
        total_cost = 0.00
        if product_qty > 1:
            total_cost = total_cost / product_qty
        res[bom_point.id] = total_cost
    return res
```

Comment: Hi Prajul, I have follow your code of logic but I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'Field product_qty not found in browse_record(mrp.bom, 812)'`. I not idea why? Because in my mrp.bom in the mrp object have this field exist. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the error is because, your functional field is in mrp.production and so the argument ids coming to the function _get_total_cost is actually the id of the records in mrp.production. The field product_qty is in the model mrp.bom. So you have to use the field bom_id in mrp.production to get the product_qty. I have edited my answer. Please refer...

Comment: Hi, I have another doubt regarding the functionality of this function. If you are calculating like this, it will give only the cost of production of one quantity of product. If you want the cost of production of the entire manufacturing order, you have to multiply the calculated total_cost with the value of the field product_qty in manufacturing order.

Comment: Thank you Prajul. You have saved me again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The type of bom_point is a list of records, so for browsing the list of records, you must define the element. In your case, you can type `bom_point[0].total_cost` for the total_cost of the first record of bom_point.